# What is a method with a boolean as returnvalue?

Tags: java

I would like to see an example of this statement: What is a method with a boolean as return value ?

Comment: notARealQuestion(): boolean // method always returns true for stupid questions

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean mymethod() {
    return true;
}
```

Not sure that's what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

A method returning boolean is a method which has `boolean` as return type and which returns true or false:

```
public boolean foo() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you use it de true and false in the same statement?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by the same statement?

Comment: @Charles, the method should return either true or false. This could be done depending on some condition.

Comment: in the code you showed me, can you use the true and false at the same time? sorry i'm new to this

okay now i get it it must be or the one or the other right?

Comment: @Charles, no a method cannot return true and false at the same time. This doesn't make sense.